# How to Scrape Text (not HTML) Table

Tags: r, datatable, scrape

I need to scrape a data table that is aligned with spaces. This is not an HTML table, but I'm having a hard time getting it right. The table looks like:

```
2017-10-28 @Westmont                100  Cal Lutheran             76           
2017-10-30 @Arizona Chr              94  E New Mexico             87           
2017-10-31 @Walsh                    91  Mt Union                 80           
2017-10-31 @Card Stritch             71  Maranatha Bap            42           
2017-11-01 @WV Tech                  82  Glenville St             80           
...
2018-03-31  Villanova                95  Kansas                   79 P        NCAA Tournament San Antonio, TX
2018-03-31  Michigan                 69  Loyola-Chicago           57 P        NCAA Tournament San Antonio, TX
2018-04-02  Villanova                79  Michigan                 62 P        NCAA I Championship San Antonio, TX
```

Because it is plain text, I pasted it into a text document and used `read.table`, but I was losing almost half the lines, and I have no idea why. I figured out how to extract the data I wanted from the lines that made it in, so I'm looking for either of two solutions:

- An easy way to scrape a table that looks like this ([link to actual data](https://www.masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=298892&sub=12801&all=1)), and get it into a dataframe (or csv).
- A way to get all of the lines of my data / a reason I'm losing a bunch of my data (I'm getting 8,861 of 16445 lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a python script that should do the job. Basically you can use your favorite programming language along with some trivial regex tricks to do it.

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
    with open ('cleanedUp.csv', 'w') as outputFile:
        regex = re.compile("\s\s+|\s@")
        for line in inputFile:
            cleanedUp = regex.split(line.strip())
            outputFile.write(','.join(cleanedUp) + '\n')
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say it, but I haven't learned python yet. If you can give me some elementary instructions on how to use this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) install python
2) create a new file and call it cleaner.py
3) paste this script over there
4) use cmd command 'python cleaner.py' to run the file

Comment: look at my previous comment. I submitted it earlier without completing it. Also I updated the script so that it reads the input from a file.

Comment: I added `text = open("file.txt","r")` to the script you wrote. Is that correct? Then I typed `python cleaner.py` into the python command prompt and got an invalid syntax error.

Comment: I updated it again so that it creates a .csv file from the data. Just copy the thing I wrote if you don't have any experience in python.

Comment: This worked great! Unfortunately, one thing I failed to describe (or even realize myself) was that some of the lines have extra columns that many do not. I updated the original post to demonstrate. Is there any way you can adjust to account for these?

Comment: Try running it after including such lines. I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: I did some tweaks to my `read.table` line, and now it seems to be working. Thanks again for your help!